# Mysql query - group by datetime period in 5 minutes

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have searched all over and can't manage to get this to work. I am trying to build a question that groups my records within 5 minutes - and displays the last entry. However I managed to get there halfway, but my query is only returning the first entry (`XX=10`).

I do have the following data:

```
ID        XX       DATETIME
N1         5       2009-05-01 13:00:00
N1        10       2009-05-01 13:04:49
N2         7       2009-05-02 14:00:00
```

and I want my group by to give me this:

```
N1      10
N2       7
```

I have uses this group by statment:

```
((60/15) * HOUR(created_on) + FLOOR(MINUTE(created_on) / 15))
```

Any one out there that has any ideas on how this query should look like?

Best regards, Joakim

Comment: Doing this for 10 minutes is mildly trivial, but it's a highly expensive task... why do you need to group like this ?

Comment: I dont follow you? Can u explain further what you mean?

Comment: You can do `GROUP BY SUBSTR(datetime,15);`. It will give you sets of 10 minutes.

Comment: Hmmm, that doesnt seems to do what I am trying to achive? I want to group a recordset and get me the latest entry.

Comment: sigh... `SELECT *, SUBSTR( datetime, 1, 16 ) as foo FROM tbl GROUP BY foo ORDER BY foo DESC LIMIT 1;` Highly unoptimized way of doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use: `((60/12) * HOUR(created_on) + FLOOR(MINUTE(created_on) / 5))`

Answer (score 1):

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_on) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_on) % 5
```

Comment: oh! this seems to be a stale question!